# Pandas dataframe: groupby one column, but concatenate and aggregate by others

Tags: python, pandas

How do I turn the below input data (Pandas dataframe fed from Excel file):

```
ID      Category                    Speaker     Price
334014  Real Estate Perspectives    Tom Smith   100
334014  E&E                         Tom Smith   200
334014  Real Estate Perspectives    Janet Brown 100
334014  E&E                         Janet Brown 200
```

into this:

```
ID      Category                    Speaker                 Price
334014  Real Estate Perspectives    Tom Smith, Janet Brown  100
334014  E&E                         Tom Smith, Janet Brown  200
```

So basiscally I want to group by Category, concatenate the Speakers, but not aggregate Price.

I tried different approaches with Pandas `dataframe.groupby()` and `.agg()`, but to no avail. Maybe there is simpler pure Python solution?

Comment: @harvpan - So you are downvoter, hmmmmm....

Comment: @jezrael, sorry but I guess you should know if the question is dupe or not. I have been downvoted many times for answering dupe. Nothing personal.

Comment: Might be a dupe, not a dupe of that question.  Doesn't cover how to get his desired price column.  Would probably have to be a combination dupe

Comment: Hmm, not sure what is the protocol in this situation. Anyway, I will upvote jezrael's answer. thanks @user3483203

Comment: @harvpan if you can find a question that aggregates by first I'll close with both as duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 possible solutions - aggregate by multiple columns and `join`:

```
dataframe.groupby(['ID','Category','Price'])['Speaker'].apply(','.join)
```

Or need aggregate only `Price` column, then is necessary aggregate all columns by `first` or `last`:

```
dataframe.groupby('Price').agg({'Speaker':','.join, 'ID':'first', 'Price':'first'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.groupby(['ID','Category'],as_index=False).agg(lambda x : x if x.dtype=='int64' else ', '.join(x))
```